# textbox and label in a form and access it in another form

Tags: vb.net

i was trying to access 3 textbox and 1 label in StudentRegistration form.
i declare it as a public through a module.

```
Module StudentInfo

Public student_no As String = StudentRegistration.lblstudentno.Text
Public lastname As String = StudentRegistration.txtlastname.Text
Public firstname As String = StudentRegistration.txtfirstname.Text
Public middlename As String = StudentRegistration.txtmiddlename.Text

End Module
```

i've tried to access it into another form but it can't automatically show when i load the form.
can you help me???

```
Private Sub Payment_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

student_no = lblstudentno.Text
 lastname = lbllastname.Text  
 firstname = lblfirstname.Text  
 middlename = lblfirstname.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Your variables are on the wrong side of the = sign. There are better ways to pass data between forms.

Comment: @OneFineDay, that second code snippet is passing data the wrong way.  Also, the first code snippet is going to get the data from the first form before it's ever been displayed, so all the controls will be empty.  Nothing you enter into the first form will ever make it to the module so, even if you fix the second code snippet, you'll never see anything in the second form.  I suggest that you read all three parts of my blog post here: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html

Comment: That is what I was saying.

Comment: @jmcilhinney but the code that written in your blog needs a button...can it be just automatically show when i load my form???

Comment: @OneFineDay, I actually meant to post "As OneFinalDay said," rather than "@OneFinalDay".  I was actually trying to agree with you but I just couldn't type good. :(

Comment: @KayeSantos, the code I posted doesn't "need a button".  Just because an example puts some code in the `Click` event handler of a `Button`, that doesn't stop you putting the same code somewhere else.  You might think about what the word "example" means.  It's not something you just copy and paste and hand into teacher.  It demonstrates a principle that you then apply.  If you want to do something when a form loads then do it when the form loads.

Comment: you might consider a different approach.  `StudentInfo` could be a class which manages the data and knows how to display the data on the right form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the code above in visual basic, supposing that "Payment" form contains four labels named lblstudentno, lbllastname, lblfirstname and lblmiddlename(not lblfirstname again...) respectively. I am not against using variables whitch have a module-level scope. I agree though with "OneFineDay" that variables and their respective values should be written vice versa in "Payment" form. Something like the following...

```
Private Sub Payment_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    lblstudentn.Text = student_no
    lbllastname.Text = lastname
    lblfirstname.Text = firstname
    lblmiddlename.Text = middlename

End Sub
```

Furthermore, i would like to mention that the student_no, lastname etc values changed only the first time i wrote some text inside the textboxes in "StudentRegistration" form. Instead of initializing the variables in StudentInfo "Module", i would suggest just declaring the variables in the module as follows...

```
Module StudentInfo

    Public student_no As String
    Public lastname As String
    Public firstname As String
    Public middlename As String

End Module
```

...and then, in some event before "Payment" form loads, update the variable's values.

```
Public Class StudentRegistration

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
        student_no = lblstudentno.Text
        lastname = txtlastname.Text
        firstname = txtfirstname.Text
        middlename = txtmiddlename.Text
        Payment.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am not sure if it all works in vb.net but i hope my comments are helpfull!!